# Neo4j Access and Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, neo4j, spatial

1. Which algo is used for showing the different color of different path ?
2. How to get access of neo4j spatial ?
3. Where to set parameter to put for the query in neo4j dashboard?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually I have created shortest distance between two location in india map but i want to show that path between that two location in green color but i could not find it anywhere. plz help me out